# aws cost and usage report throws s3 permission error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk, cloud

I am trying to generate AWS cost and usage report via Java SDK. Below is my code block for the same.

```
        credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("default").getCredentials();
   AWSCostAndUsageReportClientBuilder reportBuilder = AWSCostAndUsageReportClientBuilder.standard();

   AWSCostAndUsageReportClient costAndUsageReport =  (AWSCostAndUsageReportClient) reportBuilder
           .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
           .withRegion("us-east-1")
           .build();

   ReportDefinition reptDefinition = new ReportDefinition();

   reptDefinition.setReportName("ChandraReport123");
   reptDefinition.setTimeUnit("DAILY");
   reptDefinition.setCompression("ZIP");
   ArrayList addidtionSchemaElements = new ArrayList();
   addidtionSchemaElements.add("RESOURCES");
   reptDefinition.setAdditionalSchemaElements(addidtionSchemaElements);
   reptDefinition.setS3Bucket("etho-onnu22");
   reptDefinition.setS3Prefix("someprefix");
   reptDefinition.setS3Region("us-east-1");
   reptDefinition.setFormat("textORcsv");
   request.setReportDefinition(reptDefinition);

   PutReportDefinitionResult reportResult = costAndUsageReport.putReportDefinition(request);
```

Am getting below exception while executing the code -

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.amazonaws.services.costandusagereport.model.ValidationException:
>   Failed to verify customer bucket permission. accountId= xxxxxxx72184,
>   bucket name: etho-onnu22, bucket region: us-east-1 (Service:
>   AWSCostAndUsageReport; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   ValidationException; Request ID: xxxxxxx)     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1630)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1302)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)

Am able to upload objects to same s3 folder via s3 api. Any help or pointer is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: post the full command how you are uploading to the s3 bucket. Also, have you checked the region while running the above code ?

Comment: AWS costAndUSageReport api will generate the report and upload it to s3 bucket specified.

Answer (score 1):

AWS account 386209384616 (which is a static constant, the account number that AWS always uses to deliver these reports) must have permission to write to the bucket, via the bucket policy.

See [Getting Started, Step 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-getting-started.html#step-2) in the AWS Billing and Cost Management
User Guide (Version 2.0).  An example bucket policy is provided there.  You should change the bucket name in that policy to your bucket, but don't change the account number.  It is always `386209384616`.